# Javascript DDT don't take the $ character on csv file

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I wrote a function to test a DDT(Data Driven Testing) on test complete

**DadosTest.csv:**

```
produto,quantidade,precoesperado,descontoesperado,totalesperado
FamilyAlbum,10,$80,15%,$680
ScreenSaver,5,$20,0%,$100
MyMoney,10, $100,8%,$920
```

**My function: (is working, but I would like you to pull the $ from the file)**

```
function TestDDT()
{
  var ArquivoCSV;
  ArquivoCSV = DDT.CSVDriver("C:\\WorkspaceTestComplete\\DadosTeste.csv");
  //laco repeticao
  while(! ArquivoCSV.EOF())
  {
    Order.EscolherProduto(ArquivoCSV.Value("produto"));
    Order.DigitarQuantidade(ArquivoCSV.Value("quantidade"));

    Order.ValidarPreco("$" + ArquivoCSV.Value("precoesperado")); //concatenating works
    //Order.ValidarPreco("ArquivoCSV.Value("precoesperado")); // I want $ come from archive not from script
    Order.ValidarDesconto(ArquivoCSV.Value("descontoesperado"));
    Order.ValidarTotal("$" + ArquivoCSV.Value("totalesperado"));

    ArquivoCSV.Next();
  } 
}
```

The only way I was able to do it was to concatenate the $ with the amount that came from the csv. I did this because I found in the log that 80 (coming from csv) is different from $ 80 (detected in the field). It seems that besides the comma, he is ignoring the $. How do I select the entire string between commas, example: ", $ 999,"?

Comment: `", $ 999,"` is not really a nice CSV string since the comma before the $, is that a copy/paste typo?  This would help clarify with a real actual data sample

Comment: In other words, is `FamilyAlbum,10,$80,15%,$680` actual or is it a string since that is not valid as a CSV `"FamilyAlbum",10,"$80","15%","$680"` for example has strings

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss, with " " works. What I found curious is that in the case of 0%, 8% he found no problem. Only if the special character was in front. I should have tried and tested with the quotes in all columns

Comment: ", $999," without the blankspace. Just to clarify ..., $999, .... The javascript ignore , and $